# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que los colores de une textura se combinen con las de un polígono en openGl?

Tags: c++, opengl

Estoy creando un modelo 3d en openGl, creando el suelo usando una textura de pasto,y también creando una iglesia con el uso de prismas cuadrangulares, el detalle es que cuando dibujo el polígono este cambia de color, uno parecido al del pasto, y esto me esta causando mucho lío, ya intenté limpiar el buffer con glFlush() pero no pasa nada, alguien me puede decir como evitar esto o si ya ha tenido un problema parecido

Answer (score 0):

El problema que te pasa es que está renderizando la iglesia con la textura del pasto, y al no especificar las coordenadas de la textura (glTexCoord) son siempre la misma.

Debes deshabilitar la texturización al renderizar la iglesia, y habilitar la texturización al renderizar el pasto.

- Habilitar texturización.
- Renderizar pasto.
- Deshabilitar texturización
- Renderizar iglesia

La instrucción glFlush no limpia el buffer. Lo que hace es comunicar al controlador de OpenGL que empiece a realizar todas las tareas que le has mandado, de lo contrario se encolan y se harán en algún momento. La instrucción glFinish es similar, realiza un glFlush y espera a que la tarjeta gráfica termine todas las tareas que le has enviado.